# Explanation of "did was [verb]" structure

Tags: grammar, verbs

> All I *did was hand* someone a bag.

There are three verbs that come together. The tense of the verb *hand* confuses me. It doesn't fall into any grammar structure I know so far. It would make more sense to me if it were "All I did was *handing*..." (because *handing* is a noun form of the verb) or at least "All I did was *handed*..." (because it might be equal to "All I did was I *handed*...").

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1479263

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let's look at a similar sentence:

> 1a. [ **All I wanted** ]　*was* 〔an ice cream cone〕.
>   1b. [ **The only thing I wanted** ]　*was* 〔an ice cream cone〕.

In example 1a, ***all I wanted*** is a noun phrase.
It means ***the only thing I wanted***, so example 1b means the same thing.

Your example is similar:

> ​2. [ **All I did** ]　*was* 〔hand someone a bag〕.

Here, the bare infinitival clause ***hand someone a bag*** is used as a complement of specifying *be*.
This is one of the few functions of bare infinitival clauses—they appear mainly as complements of a few specific verbs, and one of those verbs is *be*.

If you'd like, you can call it a **nominal bare infinitive clause**, because it appears where a noun phrase would normally be expected.  But in any case, this construction is grammatical and totally normal.

Comment: I just wonder why there is not "to" - All I did was to hand a bag.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Does this help? http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/35429/230

Answer (score 0):

Your question was how to explain the verb structure of this sentence: *"All I did was **hand** someone a bag."*

I think essentially there is something that resembles a syllepsis.
Take a look at these examples for instance:

*All I did was **cry**.* --> Here it could be explained by rephrasing a little: *"all I did was [I did] cry."* The verb that follows did has to be the bare infinitive.

*"All he wanted was **to be** a girl."* --> Rephrased into: *"All he wanted was [he wanted] to be a girl"*.

---

But I also notice that when multiple to-infinitive verbs are joined in a sentence like this one, **you have to keep the "to" of the first verb**, **but you can omit the "to" of the other verbs**.

For example: *"All he wanted **to** do was (to) cry"*. Here both versions work because you can rephrase it into *"All he wanted to do was [he wanted] to cry"* or *"All he wanted to do was [he wanted to] cry"*.

Another more different example: *"All he wanted was **to** cry and (to) yell"*. Like the latest example, here both also work because you can rephrase it into *"All he wanted was to cry and [he wanted] to yell"* *"All he wanted was to cry and [he wanted to] yell"*.