# Should I use the past tense with did?

Tags: past-tense, questions, auxiliary-verbs, verb-forms

Should I use the past tense with did? For example, I was to say:

> The important question is: Did they **knew** what it means or not?

Or should I say:

> The important question is: Did they **know** what it means or not?

In other words: Should I use past tense with *did*?

I looked at this:

[Explanation of "did was [verb]" structure](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/explanation-of-did-was-verb-structure)

but it didn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, only the first verb in each clause is finite:

> They **knew** what it meant.

Here, *know* is the finite verb.  It changes form to agree with the subject (*I know, she knows*) and to indicate tense (*They know, they knew*).

To turn this into a question, we need to apply Subject-Auxiliary Inversion.  But to do that, we need an auxiliary, so we add the dummy auxiliary *do*:

> They **did know** what it meant.
>
> **Did** they **know** what it meant?　　←　*did* and *they* are inverted

Now *do* is the finite verb.  It changes form to agree with the subject (*I do, she does*) and to indicate tense (*They do, they did*).  The second verb, *know*, is non-finite and does not change form.

**Did they knew* has two finite verbs and is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

"Should I use the  past tense with did"
Answer: For the sentences you posted:

> Did they knew what it means or not?
>    Did they know what it means or not?

The answer is this: any interrogative in English (except for the verb to be) is formed like this: Helping verb + subject + main verb.

The simple present tense, declarative: They know what this means

The simple present tense, **interrogative**: **Do** they **know** [etc.]

The simple past tense, declarative: They knew what this means

The simple past tense, **interrogative**: **Did** they **know** [etc.]

Therefore, /Did they knew/ is not grammatical.

For irregular verbs (except for be), the simple past interrogative form uses DID + the subject + MAIN VERB.

DO and DID are called the  helping or auxiliary verbs used in Interrogatives.

The other question: /All I did was x/  is very different from what I explained above.

**The DID in /all I did was/ is the past of the the main verb to do and is not a helping or auxiliary verb even though it is written the same way, the function of it is not the same:**

Examples: All I do is teach English (present tense). Declarative.

All I did was teach English. (past tense of to do). Declarative