# "When did you bought/buy the sim card?"

Tags: verbs, interrogatives, do-support, conjugations

Which one is correct and why

> When did you bought the sim card?

Or

> When did you buy the sim card?

Comment: This is almost definitely a duplicate but I can't find a match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use the past tense with did?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33920/should-i-use-the-past-tense-with-did)

Comment: I suggest you review how to ask a question with a verb in English.

Answer (score 1):

The auxiliary verb "**do**" is followed by the *bare infinitive* (which is the same as the base form of the verb).

"She goes" becomes (in an emphatic statement) "she **does go**" (so, "does" is inflected for person and number, but "go" is a bare infinitive).

It becomes, in the negative, "she **doesn't go**", and in a question, "**does** she **go**?".  In the past, "**did** she **go**?".

Hence, if you want to ask when someone bought a SIM card, you have to ask "When **did** you **buy** the SIM card?".