# Correct usage of have and had

Tags: past-tense, questions

- Did he had a meeting with a prof

or

- Did he have a meeting with prof.

Which one is correct to use here: have or had?

Comment: Definitely the second one. It is the basic format of questioning in the simple past tense. __Note__: There should be a question mark at the end of a question. And "professor" is a noun, try writing the full form in formal contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use the past tense with did?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33920/should-i-use-the-past-tense-with-did)

Comment: The second one is definitely correct.

Comment: *Did* is itself a past tense auxiliary. You must have only one conjugated verb in a verb phrase, so the infinitive *have* is correct.