# Why does this sentence sound wrong?

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions

I have a friend who doesn't speak English as his first language. He sent the following message to me: "Why does this guy actually looks very similar to Oliver?" which of course sounds awkward. I tried to grammatically parse the sentence to figure out why it sounds weird but couldn't figure it out. I know that the conjugation of look is wrong (looks) but wouldn't it make sense for it to be looks because the subject is "this guy"? Why does this sentence sound weird? A grammatical breakdown would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use the past tense with did?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33920/should-i-use-the-past-tense-with-did)

Comment: Yes! Thank you.