# "All you should do is study hard" vs "All you should do is to study hard"

Tags: infinitives, cleft-constructions

> 1. All you should do is **study** hard.
> 2. All you should do is **to study** hard.

Is the one with *to* correct? When should I use *to* like that?

Comment: Those are infinitive clauses and _to_ is a marker of the infinitive; it is often deleted in _All_-clefts and _What_-clefts like the ones you mention. I.e, you can use it or you can leave it out, and it makes no difference; speaker's choice. **Here.** In other constructions, the rules are different.

Comment: So both sentences are correct, right?

Comment: And what do you mean in other constructions?

Comment: For instance, in _I want to go to Paris, to_ may not be omitted before the infinitive _go_. There are a lot of uses for infinitives; the sentences you mentioned were both [Cleft constructions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf), and they have their own rules. English grammar rules depend on constructions and constituents, not individual words.

Comment: @Snailboat: I can't closevote because of the bounty, but I think this is a duplicate of [The easiest thing to do is {to} call for a taxi](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/), which you yourself answered!

Comment: Oh, right.  Well, you can close vote in a week—my answer there probably isn't very good, though...

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm. I wouldn't disagree with you there. But almost everyone else would. This is often called an *All*-cleft. People wouldn't normally regard a *The easiest thing to do* sentence as an *All*-cleft - any more than they'd regard a [Pseudo-cleft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) as an *All*-cleft. Do you think the other link is grammatically more like an *All*-cleft or a Pseudo-cleft?

Comment: @Araucaria: I don't have an opinion on where you might draw the line between *Pseudo-cleft* and *All-cleft*. But so far as the "marked/unmarked infinitive" is concerned, I don't see much difference between ***The easiest thing to do** is [infinitive verb]* and ***All you should do** is [verb]*.

Answer (score 9):

**Short Answer**

> All you should do is study hard.
>
> All you should do is to study hard.

Both of the sentences are correct. The **to** is optional here.

---

**Long Answer**

The sentence quoted is an example of a pseudo-cleft sentence. A pseudo-cleft has a fused relative construction defining a variable whose value is specified by the foregrounded element. The usual alignment is for the element defining the variable to occur as the subject and the one giving the value as the internal component, but the reverse order is also possible.

> What I need is a cool drink. [basic pseudo-cleft]
>
> A cool drink is what I need. [reversed pseudo-cleft]

We can have a non-finite clause as the one giving the value.

> What I want to do is (to) call the police right away.

Here the **to** is optional. Why?

It depends on the verb of the fused relative clause. The pattern of the verb varies. So the cases where **to** is optional and where it's obligatory are based on the pattern the verb of the fused relative clause takes.

- Here the fused relative clause is - **What I want to do**
- Two verbs are present - **want** and **do**
- After the verb **want** we must have a **to** construction.

> I want to do it. (CORRECT)
>
> - I want do it. (INCORRECT)

The pattern after **do** is

> I play cricket. (CORRECT)
>
> I **do** play cricket (CORRECT)
>
> - I do to play cricket (INCORRECT)

Given the sentence, "**What I want to do is (to) call the police right away**", if we follow the pattern of the verb **want**, we have to use **to** before **call**, and if we want to follow the pattern of the verb **do**, we have to use only **call** without **to**.

Similarly the following sentences are correct

> **1.** What would be better is to call them beforehand. [Here **to** is obligatory. Reason? After **would be better**, the **to** is mandatory. Consider the sentence - **It would be better to call them beforehand**. If we omit **to**, the sentence would be incorrect.]
>
> **2.** All they want is to get a house for free. [Here also **to** is mandatory. Consider the sentence - **I want to get a free home**. After the verb **want** we need a **to** infinitive, as omitting **to** will result in a incorrect sentence]
>
> **3.** All the trees need now is watering. [Consider the sentence - **All the trees need watering**.]
>
> **4.** What the paper shredder does is tear the paper into small pieces. [Consider the sentence - **The paper shredder does tear the paper into small pieces**. We can't add **to** before **tear**. doing so will make the sentence incorrect.]

Consider the following sentence

> What you must do is (to) apply for special leave.

Here **to** is optional. In fused relative clauses where the verb is **do**, the **to** is optional.

When the verb of the fused relative clause has an *-ing* form, the complement also matches with an *-ing* form. Illustrated in a sentence:

> What I am doing is teaching him a lesson.

The acceptability of this next sentence is doubtful, but it can be interpreted as an elliptical form of an alternative construction involving apposition:

> What he has done is spoilt the whole thing.
>
> What he has done is ((this): he's) spoilt the whole thing.

The example above was borrowed from the 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, section 18.29, page 1388:

> Occasionally, such matching of the two verbs is extended to verbs in the perfective aspect, which can have as their counterpart an *-ed* clause:
>
> - (?) What he's *done* is *spoilt the whole thing*.
>
> This last type is, however, of doubtful acceptability, and instances of it may indeed be interpreted as ellipted forms of an alternative construction involving apposition:
>
> - What he's done is ((this) : he's) spoilt the whole thing.

Comment: Your last sentence is perfectly fine! It's not doubtful! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Just remembered something I forgot to include in my answer. I actually don't know if I am correct, but google search makes me think I am. Just for confirmation I am asking. If this sentence also correct - **What I have done is teach him a lesson**? See here it's **teach**. I think both **teach** and **taught** are correct. And this sentence is not correct, I think - **What he did was taught him a lesson**. It should be **what I he did was teach him a lesson**. Am I right?

Comment: Well, kind of. It should have been "what I did was teach him a lesson"

Comment: +1, for a nice post! :) -- Though, in my idiolect, the verb for the subordinate VP is less constrained, e.g. *"What he did was **taught** him a lesson"* would be acceptable, as the pseudo-cleft is understood to have the associated non-cleft *"He **taught** him a lesson".* But my idiolect appears to be non-standard on this issue, w.r.t. 2002 H&P *CGEL* and the 1985 Quirk et al. Oh, well. (cc. @Araucaria )

Comment: Though, be aware that your answer post is on pseudo-clefts, while the OP's examples are *all*-clefts. The two types of constructions are related, and your answer does seem to be quite applicable to the OP's question. :)

Comment: @F.E. That [might be a pond thing, methinks](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175503/cleft-sentences/175638#175638). See Pete Shor's comment. That example, "*What John did was gave me a cat*", makes my grammar ear crawl, but apparently PS finds it marginally acceptable - so maybe it is just a pondish type thing?

Comment: @Araucaria Er, your answer post over there could do with a bit of touching up, e.g. replace the all-cleft with a pseudo-cleft, and use an example using all present tense, such as *"What he does every year is gives me a pet"*. Though, the 3rd person singular does seem to be rather awkward, and perhaps the least acceptable. Though, I do see it as "logical" (or "grammatical" with respect to, er, underlying structure). :D After all, the speaker is cleaving the non-cleft version into two, and mechanically creating a cleft from the two parts, just like if it was an NP that was being put into focus.

Comment: @Araucaria How does the *"2. All you should do is to study hard."* version sound to you? (It sounds bad to my ear.)

Comment: Thanks @F.E. your comment in ELU post does explain why it's **give** in **What John did was give me a cat**. But what I found is that **gave** is also possible in that sentence, that is what I thought is possible but thought not acceptable. Now it's clear that both form - **give** and **gave** - are possible.

Comment: Oh well **gave** in that sentence is non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is that infinitives following [modal verbs](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/modal-verbs) do not need "to;" the bare infinitive is appropriate.  There is no special construction needed for this to be true.  Modal verbs are helping verbs like *can, could, should, would, must* and *may* (and others.)

*Want*, used as a counter example in the comments, is not a modal verb, and so we use the full infinitive with it.

This can get more complicated with phrases like:

> I would like to go to the park.

Here the modal verb **would** is operating on the infinitive **like** and so the bare infinitive is appropriate.  This doesn't extend to the infinitive **to go** that follows; there it is acting as a noun (an object, specifically.)

Comment: Are you saying that *to* is ungrammatical here?

Comment: @Araucaria It really depends on the construction of the sentence.  With the particular wording of the OP's question, it's optional.  If it were something like "What I think you should do is (to) go dancing," then both versions of the sentence, with and without "to" are grammatical, but the version without "to" flows better and is far more common in American English.  Including the "to" sounds odd and a bit old fashioned.