# Is it, kill your daughter or killing your daughter?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

THE SOURCE: LOST (tv series)

> LOCKE: You told her not to talk to me. That made her pointless... Now, Charles, it's clear you're not afraid to die. So, there's only one way to motivate you to tell me what I want to know. Soon, this will all be over. I'll get what I want. And I'll finally leave this island. And when I do, the first thing I'm going to do is **kill** your daughter...Penny.

Why the writer did use “kill” instead of **killing**

- Killing you daughter is the first thing I am ...

Comment: @Man_From_India  *"The first thing I'm going to do is **killing** your daughter,"* is certainly **not** correct.  Use the bare infinitive after "do", not the gerund.

Comment: Bavyan, please refere to this answer for explanation https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/48750/3463

Comment: @Man_From_India  *"The first thing I'm going **to be doing** is **killing**"*, perhaps.

Comment: @Man_From_India  yes, that's fine.  I don't presume to understand the "why" of English grammar patterns, but for some reason it's ok to start with the gerund.