# was buy , was to buy, or was buying

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1. The first thing I did **was buy** the tickets to go to Europe.
> 2. The first thing I did **was to buy** the tickets to go to Europe.
> 3. The first thing I did **was buying** the tickets to go to Europe.

Can someone tell me which of the following sentences is correct and why?

Comment: To my untrained ear they all sound OK, probably because in '1' the "buy" leans toward being a noun...

Comment: You could also say "The first thing I did *was I bought* the tickets to go to Europe." This option is probably the least formal.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/96243/33000

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/35429/33000

Answer (score 1):

They would all be perfectly acceptable to any (British at least) native English speaker.

Sentence one would be the most common form used, it's slightly less formal than the second (most people wouldn't use the infinitive form of the verb when talking about themselves).

The third sentence is more of a narrative. It comes across as less of a statement and more of a first person past-tense dialogue rather than a statement of past actions.