# How "Is + verb" possible?

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives, ellipsis, parsing, bare-infinitives

We can use *a full infinitive* or *a gerund*  as a complement of the 'be'-verb. For example,

> The first thing I do in the morning is *to check* my mobile phone.
>
> The first thing I do in the morning is *checking* my mobile phone.

But I've seen the bare infinitive used in such construction with no real difference:

> The first thing I do in the morning is *check* my mobile phone.

Thus, bare infinitive is used *when the finite element of the first verb is a form of "do"* : [Using bare infinitive after 'does'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96229/using-bare-infinitive-after-does).

Now, my question is whether it's a case of elision, such as *"The first thing I do in the morning is **[that I]** check my mobile phone."* or is there any other grammatical explanation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using bare infinitive after 'does'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96229/using-bare-infinitive-after-does)

Comment: @Cardinal, that question tells about using bare infinitive after 'does'. But I want to know whether it's a case of elision :*"The first thing I do in the morning is [that I] check my mobile phone."*

Comment: the case of bare infinitive is just a form of what people usually call "spoken English", which is normally seen in casual communication. It is non-formal so it does not have to be grammatically correct.

Comment: @LêGiaLễ: your comment strongly implies that it is not "grammatically correct". On what do you base that conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

> The first thing I do in the morning is check my mobile phone

This is perfectly grammatical and perhaps the most common. When the subject has a form of "do", the infinitive is used. You can put "to" there, but it is optional.

> The first thing I do in the morning is checking my mobile phone

The sentence above is not grammatical. It'll only be grammatical if the verb "do" is progressive as in:

> The first thing I was doing was checking my mobile phone.