# The only action she performed was to withdraw/withdrawing the money - why both are ok?

Tags: usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

We know that when the verb in the subject is a form of the verb "do", we have to use the infinitive form of a verb.
For example,

> The only thing I can do is (to) give him money as compensation. - correct

> The only thing I can do is giving him money as compensation. - not correct or less idiomatic

However, why when the verb in the subject is not "do", both genrund and infinitive form are acceptable?

**Example 1**

> (1) The only action she performed was to withdraw the money.

> (2) The only action she performed was withdrawing the money.

**Example 2**

> (1) The task he does might be to turn on the TV.

> (2) The task he does might be turning on the TV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using bare infinitive after 'does'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96229/using-bare-infinitive-after-does)

Comment: *We know that when the verb in the subject is a form of the verb "do", we have to use the infinitive form of a verb.* <-- That isn't the reason to use the infinitive. We'd also have to use the infinitive if the subject were "what I want", for example, or even "the idea".