# What verb to choose: "DO all you do is sit here?" or "IS all you do is sit here?"

Tags: word-choice, difference

1. Is all you do is sit here?
2. Do all you do is sit here?

Which of the two is correct? From my opinion it's the first one but it's still awkward. However, the second one also seems to make sense.

Comment: None! *What* all you do is sit here?

Comment: @MaulikV That's actually not the right answer either.

Comment: How can you have two main verbs in a single sentence? **Is he is here?** Would that make any sense to you?

Comment: I was thinking from the point of view of the declarative sentence: "**Sit here is all you do**" so we get "All you do is sit here?" as an exclamative interrogative sentence. But I need a clear interrogative sentence.

Comment: How about this one: **Is sitting here all you do?**

Comment: @CookieMonster yeh, I know about the "sitting" way but I'd like to avoid it just yet.

Comment: @snailplane How about "***All what you do is sit here?***" then?

Comment: @Soha That's also ungrammatical, at least in Standard English.

Comment: @snailplane I'm really confused with the difference between using "**to**" or not using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that the first seems grammatical whereas the second is definitely not.

"All that you do is to sit here" or "All you do is sit here" are perfectly acceptable declarative sentences. Making them interrogative while retaining the infinitive does seem to lead to a doubled verb as in "Is all that you do is to sit here" or "Is all you do is sit here." The only way to make sense of the doubled verb is to assume an ellipsis such as "Is it true that all you do is to sit there."

I agree that the interrogatives so formed with the doubled verb sound awkward (or at least colloquial). That awkwardness can be avoided by using a participle instead of an infinitive.

"Is sitting here all that you do" or "Is sitting here all you do" sound better to me, but that is esthetics, not grammar.

Comment: Alright. In that case then, the subject of the sentence is actually **all** and not **all you do**. What do you know.

Comment: @Monster I am not sure I follow that comment, but I made some edits to clarify my original answer, which did not address the doubled verb. Perhaps you were commenting on the unrevised answer. I think that "all [that] you do" is the subject of the second "is."

Comment: Related discussion: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/the-easiest-thing-to-do-is-to-call-for-a-taxi/35429#35429

Answer (score 5):

The correct way of forming the question is

> Is all you do sit here?

This follows naturally from the statement form

> All you do is sit here

by the standard question-forming process of inverting the verb ("is") and the subject ("all you do").

The result sounds rather clumsy, though, so I'd recommend either rephrasing (say, as "Is sitting here all you do?"), or adding a word between "do" and "sit" - for example,

> Is all you do just sit here?

Adding the extra word gives a more natural rhythm to the sentence, which is probably why some people want to insert "is", but to me at least that's ungrammatical due to repeating the main verb "is".

Comment: `Is all you do sit here?` is definitely not valid English

Comment: @Jason: Do you have a source to back that up?

Comment: Yes, native English speaker. You are definitely missing a verb.

Comment: @Jason the verb is "**sit**"

Comment: @Jason: That's not really good enough - I'm a native English speaker myself, and I (and all the others I've asked) find "Is all you do sit there" perfectly grammatical (if a little clunky). There's no verb missing - the main verb is "Is". I'm interested - which of the following do you believe are correct/incorrect? (1) All you do is sit here. (2) Is all you do is sit here? (3) Is all you do just sit here? (4) Your name is Jason. (5) Is your name Jason? (6) Is your name is Jason? (7) All you need is here. (8) Is all you need here? (9) Is all you need is here?

Comment: We need to distinguish between what is grammatical and what is graceful. Virtually any way that the related declarative sentence is made into an interrogative containing an infinitive seems to be awkward. "Is to sit here all that you do" is, in my opinion at least, grammatical, but few native speakers would ever use it. What is clear and idiomatic is to use the present participle instead of the infinitive. The OP seems not to want to use the participle. Retaining the infinitive can be done grammatically, but it will be very ugly English.

Comment: You can't "do" "sit here." "Sit here" cannot be "done". You can "sit here" (sit being the verb). You can say "What are you doing? Sitting here?" as "Sitting here" can be done. But you cannot say "Is all you do sit here?" since you can't do "sit here."

1) C, 2) C, 3) I, 4) C, 5) C, 6) I, 7) C, 8) C, 9) I

Comment: @Jason: Consider: *Q: You don't sit here, do you? // A: You're wrong! I do sit here.* So actually "sit here" *is* something you can "do"! But in fact that isn't actually relevant here - there isn't actually a "do sit", it just happens that those words end up together when you form the question, just as "name Jason" and "need here" end up together in the other examples. Can you explain why you think the question from 4 is 5, and from 7 is 8 (which in both cases I agree with), yet you disagree with "Is all you do sit here" when it's formed from (1) in the *exact same way*?

Comment: The difference is that [Your name] and [All you need] are nouns, whereas "sit" is a verb. 4: [noun1] is [noun2], 5: Is [noun1] [noun2]?, 7: [noun] is [preposition], 8: Is [noun] [preposition], 1: [All you do] [is sit] [preposition] <-- different. 2: Is [All you do] [is sit] [preposition]? In the same vein, you wouldn't say "All you do sit here", you'd have to say "All you do IS sit here"

Comment: Sorry @Jason, that makes no sense: (i) The bit that corresponds to \[Your name] and \[All you need] is not "sit" but "All you do"; it's a noun phrase just like the rest. (ii) There are no prepositions in any of the examples; do you mean "adverb"? (iii) The complement is "sit here", a verb, but it's acting as a noun phrase here. (iv) All the sentences are of the form "X is Y", and their question forms are "Is X Y?". (v) Of course you wouldn't say "\*All you do sit here" - that has no main verb. But you wouldn't put "is" twice ("\*All you do is is sit here"), right? So why do so in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> Do you just sit here?

or

> Is sitting here all you do?