# Subject complement "Noun phrase + Be + (to) bare infinitive"

Tags: sentence-construction, bare-infinitives, subject-complement

Is it right to use a bare infinitive as a subject complement as in the following quote?

> "Its true purpose **is convince** shoppers that your product is the preferred choice"

Another example:

> "Their purpose **is convince** holders of political office of the importance of their industry but also to inform them about their expert knowledge and responsibility in their respective industry."

Sources:

http://www.businessessentials.co.za/2017/07/14/brand-toolkit/

http://www.serviceplan.co.kr/en/397.html

I am aware of that bare infinitive can be used when the sentence contains **do** as in [this example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/the-easiest-thing-to-do-is-to-call-for-a-taxi/35429#35429):

> The thing to do is [call for a taxi].

Comment: The quote says "A brand's first mandate **is to** ____" but your question asks "is it right to say *It's true purpose **is** convince*" (without the *to*).  Can you clarify which structure you're asking about?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: The examples you found look like typos.  I'd guess that the "to" in each case was simply missed in editing.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I think you are right. Someone else just told me the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither reads as correct to me. Both sound like they're written badly. I'd write them as "is to convince" or "is convincing", depending on how you're using tense in the rest of the piece. Since the latter part of the second example also uses "to inform", the first form should be used. "Their purpose is to convince"

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. You are right that the first part is not consistent with second.