# How to use infinitive after 'to be' verbs?

Tags: infinitives

I wonder how an infinitive should be used after a `to be` verbs, i.e. does the infinitive used this way have to use 'to' or not. For example:

> 1. All you have to do is sit (**or to sit or sitting??**) and wait.
> 2. So, what we did in this lecture was create (**to create or creating??**) a new style for our  activity ...

Comment: I hope this helps :) http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/explanation-of-did-was-verb-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *All you have to do is (to) sit and wait.*
2. *So, what we did in this lecture was (to) create a new style for our activity ...*

It must be an infinitival verb phrase. Gerund-participial clauses (the -*ing* kind) are not permitted here.

The bare infinitival (without the *to*) is usual, but where the subject noun phrase contains *do* in a relative clause, as it does in both your examples, *to* can be optionally added.

Comment: Gerund is not permitted here?!  Why?

Comment: @JasonStack You would need the verb "be" as in  _All you have to do is (to) be sitting and waiting_. Note that you could also say _All you have to be doing is sitting and waiting_.

Answer (score 2):

In the specific types of expressions you are citing (namely, "All you have to do is ..." and "What we did in this lecture was ..."), the verb in the predicate can include "to" or can omit "to" and still be considered perfectly natural.

All of these are fine:

*All you have to do is sit and wait.*

*All you have to do is to sit and wait.*

*What we did in this lecture was create a new style for our activity.*

*What we did in this lecture was to create a new style for our activity.*

Sentences that take this form are a type of expressions known as *pseudo-cleft* sentences. As Günter Rohdenburg writes in ["Clarifying Structural Relationships in Cases of Increased Complexity in English" (Making Meaningful Choices in English: Dimensions, Perspectives, Methodology, and Evidence; Rainer Schulze, editor; Gunter Narr Verlag, 1998; page 194)](https://books.google.com/books?id=kp0D8UX9lQoC&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq="pseudo-cleft"+"optional") :

> English boasts a wealth of contructions involving various function words which are omissible in certain contexts....
>
> Apart from certain verbal complements, the optional use of the infinitive marker is characteristic of pseudo-cleft constructions as in ...
>
> All you can do is (to) wait for the results.
>
> What she did was (to) wait for the results.

Rohdenburg goes on to cite evidence indicating that ommitting the "to" in these constructions is becoming more common than in past centuries, especially in more informal usage and in American usage compared to, for example, British usage--all of which conforms with my own impressions. Americans more commonly omit the "to" than include it nowadays, especially in more informal usage, I think.

---

Please note that using a form of the verb with an -ing suffix in the predicate (for example, *All you have to do is sitting and waiting*, or *What we did in this lecture was creating a new style for our activity*) is ungrammatical and would never occur in English--*unless* the "do" verb before the copula (the copula being the to-be verb in the middle of the sentence) is already in an -ing form:

All you are do*ing* is sitt*ing* and wait*ing*.

What I am do*ing* in this lecture is creat*ing* a new style for our activity.

---

Note also that if the verb in the predicate is *itself* a form of "to be," then inclusion of "to" is mandatory:

All (that) we wanted was *to be* free. (correct)

All (that) we wanted was be free. (ungrammatical)

What we want is *to be* free. (correct)

What we want is be free. (ungrammatical)