# Argue or argument

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, nouns

The sentence below is extracted from vocabulary for IELTS book (recording scripts part).

> But nowadays all we seem to do is argue and that causes a lot of conflict between us.

Can we use 'argument' instead of 'argue' here? Why?

Comment: You asked this same question 8 hours ago. Possible duplicate of [gerund and noun applications](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/201020/gerund-and-noun-applications)