# "All I did was do something" is correct?

Tags: objects, direct-objects, indirect-objects

I saw several the following examples beginning with "All I did was":

1. All I did was see something.
2. All I did was hire her.
3. All I did was tell him the truth.

Are these sentences correct?

Why a verb that following "was" is in a bare form, instead of a form that would be more appropriate for an object?

If those are correct, what is an object?

If those are grammatically incorrect, so how does a correct form look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/explanation-of-did-was-verb-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the link to previous questions, you will find further links of undoubted interest. Nevertheless, in English as spoken by native speakers you will find usages comparable with the examples quoted by the OP. Such usages would certainly not raise eyebrows amongst highly educated native speakers.

If you define "correct" by reference to how such people use their language then there is nothing wrong with any of the examples. If they do not appear to comply with rules defined by grammarians, then it is up to the grammarians to revise their rules.